Significant current leakage from collector to base with 2N2222 NPN BJT (12v, 1mA leakage)
According to 2N2222 NPN datasheet, the transistor's collector-base breakdown voltage is 75V, and collector-emitter breakdown is 40V. So the transistor should work with 12V at collector, in the simple setup below.
Leakage current from collector to base is expected to be much less than a milliamp, most of the time even less than a microamp.
Here is the setup I built (on a breadboard, if it matters):

The expectation, of course, is nearly zero current flowing through collector-emitter, that is, collector voltage is equal to VDC.
In my case, however, when VDC is higher than about 9.6V, the transistor starts conducting current, but not to the emitter - to the base. The voltage at the base beings to rise as I increase voltage higher than 9.6V. When I reach 12V (the voltage I need for my application), the voltage at the base settles to about 0.093V, that corresponds to a current of about 1mA through the resistor R1. That same current I observe through the resistor R2, since the voltage across the resistor is 2.72V. So it suggests the all the leakage goes through the base (none to the emitter, since the current through both R1 and R2 is nearly equal, accounting for measurement error). With VDC 24V, the leakage to the base reaches about 5mA with that same setup.
In summary, current from collector to base beings to leak when VDC rises higher than 9.6V.
I had multiple 2N2222 transistors and I checked the setup with 4 different, new transistors, never in use before. The observations are the same, maybe with slight variation.
I also have a BC337 transistor. Its pinout (in TO-92 case) is the same as the one of 2N2222, so I didn't change the setup in any way, just plugged a new transistor on the board.
I observe no leakage current with this transistor, even with VDC 24V. I observe VDC voltage at the collector of the transsitor, signifying no current flow.
Are the 2N2222 transistors I tested faulty, or is the observed current leakage expected with the supplied voltage for this transistor model?

Most likely user error. You probably have a P2N2222 which has a different (reversed) pinout to a 2N2222 and are using the pinout for the 2N2222. Or vice-versa.
The first is C-B-E and the second E-B-C.
Typical E-B breakdown is around 9V. Causing E-B breakdown can also permanently reduce the hFE.
You can check the datasheet, assuming you came by the parts from a reputable source, or you can use a multimeter in diode mode. The C-B junction of this type of transistor will have a slightly lower forward voltage than the E-B junction under the same conditions (avoid touching the part and heating it between measurements). I get 685 (B-C ) vs. 691 (B-E) for a similar transistor.

I couldn't determine the collector and emitter using multimeter. The base is indeed the middle pin, but the forward voltage to the two other pins was 0.742V, and neither was higher than the other. But I tried the setup assuming the opposite pinout, and indeed, it worked! I'd never thought it was such a silly mistake. Thanks!


Are the 2N2222 transistors I tested faulty

They're either faulty, fake or you connected them incorrectly.
